# Is a chain of people more efficient for transporting something than each person carrying from A to B?

Tags: logic

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but if anyone can point me to a more relevant Stackexchange please do.

Imagine I need to transport a certain number of items from point A to D. The number of people is less than the number of items. There are not enough people to make a chain where each person can touch each other, so each person must walk back and forth to transport it.

Is it more efficient to have each person take an item and do the full trip, or is it better to have each person at a station and just cover a certain part of the full distance?

I tried to work this out on paper and in my first example with 3 people carrying 6 items it was more efficient to walk the full length. However 6 is too convenient because it means they're always operating at fully capacity and nobody is left standing around.  When I used 7 items the result was the same, but I'm not sure the reason for this, or if it applies to bigger samples.

In the example I used 3 people carrying 7 items.

**With each person carrying the full length**

It takes 60 seconds to travel from A to D.

```
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| seconds elapsed | items at A | people at A | people at D | items at D |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|               0 |          7 | 1,2,3       | -           |          0 |
|              60 |          4 | -           | 1,2,3       |          3 |
|             120 |          4 | 1,2,3       | -           |          3 |
|             180 |          1 | -           | 1,2,3       |          6 |
|             240 |          1 | 1           | 2,3         |          6 |
|             300 |          0 | -           | 1,2,3       |          7 |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

**With four stations and one person responsible for each link:**

The asterisk shows that person is carrying an item. The distance between each station is 20 seconds, so one full trip should take the same time as in the previous example.

```
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| seconds elapsed | items at A | people at A | people at B | people at C | people at D | items at D |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|               0 |          7 | 1           | 2           | 3           | -           |          0 |
|              20 |          6 | -           | 1*,2        | 3           | -           |          0 |
|              40 |          6 | 1           | -           | 2*,3        | -           |          0 |
|              60 |          5 | -           | 1*,2        | -           | 3*          |          1 |
|              80 |          5 | 1           | -           | 2*,3        | -           |          1 |
|             100 |          4 | -           | 1*,2        | -           | 3*          |          2 |
|             120 |          4 | 1           | -           | 2*,3        | -           |          2 |
|             140 |          3 | -           | 1*,2        | -           | 3*          |          3 |
|             160 |          3 | 1           | -           | 2*,3        | -           |          3 |
|             180 |          2 | -           | 1*,2        | -           | 3*          |          4 |
|             200 |          2 | 1           | -           | 2*,3        | -           |          4 |
|             220 |          1 | -           | 1*,2        | -           | 3*          |          5 |
|             240 |          1 | 1           | -           | 2*,3        | -           |          5 |
|             260 |          0 | -           | 1*,2        | -           | 3*          |          6 |
|             280 |          0 | -           | 1           | 2*,3        | -           |          6 |
|             300 |          0 | -           | 1           | 2           | 3*          |          7 |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Just a thought but wouldn't a chain force the speed to be determined by the slowest worker?  Meanwhile without the chain the speed goes by the average.

Comment: That sounds sensible to me, and I can imagine in a practical world there's a lot more to consider like whether people can move freely (if it's a narrow hall or something a chain will be better) and the speed stuff and queuing problems like you said but for my question I'm imagining a fantasy world where everybody moves exactly the same pace and are totally synchronized

Comment: In that case, assuming zero time in passing items between workers, my intuition tells me it doesn't matter how you do it, time to complete would be the same.